# SwaggerHub mock server with externalValue example

Tags: swagger, openapi, swaggerhub

I'm getting 406 Not Acceptable responses when I'm trying to use the `externalValue` property in an example object on the swaggerhub mocked server. 
Am I doing something wrong or this feature is not implemented on the swaggerhub mocking server?

#### API snippet

```
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK!
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
              examples:
                example:
                  externalValue: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
            application/pdf:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
              examples:
                sampleFile:
                  externalValue: "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
```

#### Postman API call

[image: postman call]

#### open api documentation

[examples  externalValue property](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwaggerHub mock server only supports JSON, XML, and YAML responses. If you request any other media types (e.g. `Accept: application/pdf` or `Accept: image/png`), a 406 response is returned.

SwaggerHub mock server does NOT support `externalValue` for sample responses. The mock ignores those examples and generates sample responses by other means, e.g. based on the response `schema`.

From the [documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/api-auto-mocking.html#features) (emphasis mine):

> - Generates **JSON, XML and YAML responses** based on response schemas and examples.
> - Supports `enum`, `default`, `example`, and `examples` (the first example is returned), **except for `externalValue` examples**.

Comment: I saw this documentation you linked in but I thought JSON, XML and YAML responses are mentioned there only because of response Content-Type you can set as default. Thank you kindly for your explanation.